# storing input textfield on flutter

Tags: flutter, search, voice

Im implementing voice search on flutter. Here I have an icon for voice search and when clicked, a function is called and the resulting string is stored in String _text.

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: (){
      _listen(); 
       })},
  icon: Icon(_isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none, ),
),
```

I also have a searchbar with a controller txt where the inputs are stored

```
TextField(
  controller: txt, 
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
  hintText: 'What are you looking for?',),
 onSubmitted: (txt){}
```

my problem is how can i store the _text string to the searchbar when they use voice search?

Comment: just use setState or your stateManagement thing and directly ```_controller.text = _voiceText```

Comment: you might be asking for this, `txt.text = searchBarString`, but still the question is not clear